# Virtualenv/Virtualenvwrapper accessing global packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I create a new virtual environment using virtualenvwrapper and run `pip freeze`, the list is empty. However,I am still able to execute global packages that are *not* installed inside my virtual environment, like flask and flake8.

I thought that the default `--no-site-packages` option isolates the global site packages from the virtual environment, so that I can't use them.

I'm not sure if my understanding of virtual environments is incorrect or if my system is misconfigured.

Is this behavior expected? If not, I'll keep troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute global packages"? Are you able to import the libraries in a Python shell or script using your virtual environment, or are you just able to run the CLI executables that those packages provide?

Comment: I'm able to run the CLI executable but I haven't tried importing the libraries from the Python shell. I'll try that when I get home. Is being able to run the CLI executable normal behavior?

Comment: CLI tools like `flake8` are added to your `PATH`, and a new virtual environment won't remove them. If you install `flake8` in your virtual environment, however, it will supersede the global version. If you don't want this to happen, remove these packages from your global environment.

Comment: It seems that I am able to run the CLI executable and import the libraries from the Python shell. I  went ahead and imported a package which doesn't have a CLI executable (`jinja2`) as an experiment and it worked.

If this is the correct behavior then I misunderstood how virtual environments work. I'll clean up the the global packages to avoid future dependency issues. Thanks.